# How Can I Found Admin Directory

Tags: admin, wp-admin

I need to install a plug-in to my client's website but I don't know admin path. Probably he changed the directory with a plug-in but I can't find it.

I have admin, FTP and database login/pass.  I just need to know admin directory. How can I find that?

Note: It's midnight here, so I can't call my client at this time.